# PHP: Sort array according to another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem in php, i tried searching but i only got more confused. I need to sort an array according to another array using the "priority" key value.

This is the order i need it filtered with.

```
$custom_order = array(
    array('priority' => 0, 'field_id' => 'password'),
    array('priority' => 1, 'field_id' => 'username')
);
```

And this is the array that needs to be filtered

```
$default_order = array(
    'name' => array(
        'username' => array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'priority'    => 0
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'type'        => 'password',
            'priority'    => 1
        ),
    ),
);
```

And this is the order that i would like to get

```
$final_order = array(
    'name' => array(
       'password' => array(
            'type'        => 'password',
            'priority'    => 0
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'priority'    => 1
        ),
    ),
);
```

I'm confused, i'm not sure whether i should use uasort, or array_intersect, by reading other articles about it i got more confused. Can anybody please explain how would i go to sort the array in this way?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If priority is the actual sort criteria, then usort would be an easy way:

```
usort( $array['name'], function($a, $b) {
    return ($a->priority < $b->priority) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This just compares the value of priority between elements of the array. If not, perhaps you could enhance your example to show how the sort should actually be determined.

EDIT: Based on the clarified question.

Because of the structure of your arrays, I don't believe that you will be able to just use PHP functions.

First, arrange the priorities in a form better for prioritzing:

```
$priorities = array();
foreach ($custom_order as $item) {
    $priorities[$item->field_id] = $item->priority;
}
```

Then assign updated priorities to the $default items:

```
$final_order = array();
foreach ($default_order as $item) {
    $item->priority = $priorities[$item->type];
}
```

Then do the sort originally suggested to get them in priority order:

```
usort( $final_order['name'], function($a, $b) {
    return ($a->priority < $b->priority) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i've explained myself badly. I've updated my question with a more appropriate example. Yes, "priority" is the comparison value i'd like to use. I want $default_order to be sorted based on the "priority" set into $custom_order